# calculate tile size of google map at zoom level n

Tags: php, google-maps, cluster-analysis, mercator

Hey. I have a maps application that uses google maps. I get the bounds off the map, and then I do some clustering markers on that grounds, but to be able to have the clusters stay at the same place, I'd like to know how to make the boundaries that I pass snap into the tilegrid that google uses. The quadtree algorithm they use for their map essentially what I'm asking for is

how do I get the bounds for the tiles that the viewport is in. I've tried to illustrate it :)
[image: google tiles viewport cluster]

If I do the cluster calc on the tile bounds and not the viewport, when I split it up in a grid, the clusters will stay in the same place, because the grid will be absolute at each zoom level.

Also this allows for better query caching, as the queries will be a lot similar when the bounds have to "snap in" to the tiles, AND the user will be able to pan with markers in proximity being displayed already.

**UPDATE**

I'm starting over...

I've got this

```
    function TileMyBounds($sx, $sy, $nx, $ny, $zoom)
{

        function TileMyBounds($sx, $sy, $nx, $ny, $zoom)
{
    list($nmx,$nmy) = $this->LatLonToMeters($ny/1000000, $nx/1000000);
    list($ntx, $nty) = $this->MetersToTile($nmx, $nmy, $zoom);
    $nbounds = $this->TileLatLonBounds($ntx, $nty, $zoom);
    list($smx,$smy) = $this->LatLonToMeters($sy/1000000, $sx/1000000);
    list($stx, $sty) = $this->MetersToTile($smx, $smy, $zoom);
    $sbounds = $this->TileLatLonBounds($stx, $sty, $zoom);

    $step = ($sbounds[3]-$sbounds[1])*1000000;

    return array($sbounds[0]*1000000, $sbounds[1]*1000000, $nbounds[2]*1000000, $nbounds[3]*1000000, $step);
}
```

and the function where I use it looks like this:

```
function clusterGrid($zoom,$nelt,$nelg,$swlt,$swlg)
    {
    $singlemarkers = array();
    $clusters = array();

list($swlg, $swlt, $nelg, $nelt, $step) = $this->TileMyBounds($swlg, $swlt, $nelg, $nelt, $zoom);
$calcbounds = $this->TileMyBounds($swlg, $swlt, $nelg, $nelt, $zoom);
$queryconcat = "";
$length_lng = ceil(($nelg-$swlg)/$step);
$length_lat = ceil(($nelt-$swlt)/$step);
$orgnelg = $nelg;
$orgswlt = $swlt;

for($i=0;$i < $length_lng + 1; $i++) {
    $nelg -= $step;
    $temp_swlt = $swlt;

    for($j=0; $j < $length_lat + 1; $j++) {

        $temp_swlt += $step;

        if($nelg > $orgnelg) continue;
        if($temp_swlt > $nelt) continue;
        if($nelg < $swlg) continue;
        if($temp_swlt < $orgswlt) continue;

        $q = $this->db->select('
            COUNT(*) AS CO,
            (MAX(lat)+MIN(lat))/2 AS lat,
            (MAX(lng)+MIN(lng))/2 AS lng')
        ->where('`lat` BETWEEN '.$temp_swlt.' AND '.($temp_swlt+$step).' AND 
            `lng` BETWEEN '.($nelg-$step).' AND '.$nelg)
        ->get('markers');
        $queryconcat += $this->db->last_query(); 
        $result = $q->row_array();

        if($result['CO'] == 0) {
            continue;
        }
            $clusters[] = array('lat' => ($result['lat']), 'lng' => ($result['lng']), 'size' => $result['CO']);
        }
    }
return array('singlemarkers' => '', 'clustermarkers' => $clusters, 'bounds' => $calcbounds, 'lengths' => array($length_lng, $length_lat));  
}
```

**UPDATE!!!! 12/03/2011 - Almost there**
The tiles are somewhat precise, yet not entirely, so when panning around, the clusters can "move around" a little. Due to the fact that the `$step = ($sbounds[3]-$sbounds[1])*1000000;` calculation is not always the same at each zoom level, as I would've expected because I would think that a tile would have the same width and length in lat and lon as any other tile at the same zoom level.

Comment: Hi @Jakob, do you know on how to implement that in Java? I am developing an Android application that uses a static image map then mark the current location of the user. In order to get the pixel coordinate of the current viewport, I need to know the whole size of the google map at a specified zoom level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But something's not quite right. Can anyone tell why I'm not getting the viewport coordinates when I pass in swlg,swlat,nelg,nelat and the zoom level

You want to solve the space-filling-curve equation first with all 4 bounds coordinates.

```
list($lng, $lat) = array ($row['lng'], $row['lat']);
list($mx, $my) = $mercator->LatLonToMeters($lat, $lng);
list($tx, $ty) = $mercator->MetersToTile($mx, $my, MAXZOOM);
list($tx, $ty) = array ($tx, ((1 << MAXZOOM) - 1) - $ty );
list($minx, $miny) = $this->PixelsToMeters( $tx*$this->tileSize, $ty*$this->tileSize, $zoom );
list($maxx, $maxy) = $this->PixelsToMeters( ($tx+1)*$this->tileSize, ($ty+1)*$this->tileSize, $zoom );
return array($minx, $miny, $maxx, $maxy);
```

or

```
list($lng, $lat) = array ($row['lng'], $row['lat']);
list($mx, $my) = $mercator->LatLonToMeters($lat, $lng);
list($tx, $ty) = $mercator->MetersToTile($mx, $my, MAXZOOM);
list($tx, $ty) = array ($tx, ((1 << MAXZOOM) - 1) - $ty );
$bounds = $this->TileBounds($tx, $ty, $zoom);
list($minLat, $minLon) = $this->MetersToLatLon($bounds[0], $bounds[1]);
list($maxLat, $maxLon) = $this->MetersToLatLon($bounds[2], $bounds[3]);
return array($minLat, $minLon, $maxLat, $maxLon);
```

EDIT: Problem is solved. OP answered in private Mail:

Comment: @epitah - have you got any clues at to why the tilesize seems to differ on one zoom level, for there to be any logic in tiles shouldn't this line: $sbounds[2]-$sbounds[0] , ALWAYS give the same result, at the same ZOOM level, no matter what tile I calculate?

Comment: @epitah please look at my edit of the original post, there's only a little bit of tweaking left.

Comment: @Jakob: I've send you an e-mail but this looks to me like an error. Did you look at the example: foreach(range($tminy, $tmaxy) as $ty)
   foreach(range($tminx, $tmaxx) as $tx)
   {
    $quadtree = $this->QuadTree($tx, $ty, $zoom);
    
    $arr[$quadtree] = $this->TileLatLonBounds($tx, $ty, $zoom);
   }
he is using a quadtree.